# Disable click event while zooming in CanvasJS

Tags: javascript, charts, canvasjs

Is there any way to disable the click event while utilizing the zoom feature with CanvasJS?

The click event that I have set up opens up a separate pop up and works just fine. The zoom feature enabled works great as well until it triggers the click event while zooming and opens the pop up.

The only thing that I have been able to find was a comment on their site asking the same thing with one of the developers stating it would be fixed soon around a month or so; however, that was in November of 2014. I was unable to find anything in their forums as well.

Thank you for any help that can be provided.

Edit - Code example below.

Html:

```
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 360px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  zoomEnabled: true,
  zoomType: 'x',
  data: [
    {
      type: "column",
      dataPoints: [
        { x: 10, y: 71 },
        { x: 20, y: 55 },
        { x: 30, y: 50 },
        { x: 40, y: 65 },
        { x: 50, y: 95 },
        { x: 60, y: 68 },
        { x: 70, y: 28 },
        { x: 80, y: 34 },
        { x: 90, y: 14 }
      ],
      click: details
    }                   
  ]
});

chart.render();

function details()
{
    alert('click event');
}
```

Link to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fpq0uaL4/)